# I don't get latitude and longitude

Tags: android, android-gps

Actually I don't get latitude and longitude from this code.

```
package com.example.reyadmahabub.location;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LocationCallback callback;
    private LocationRequest request;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient( this );
        callback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult( locationResult );
                for (Location location:locationResult.getLocations()){
                    double lat=location.getLatitude();
                    double lon=location.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,lat+","+lon, 



 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    }

                }
            };
            createLocationRequest();


    }



 private void createLocationRequest() {
        request = new 

LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY )
                    .setInterval( 2500 ).setFastestInterval( 5000 );
```

//here it is activity permissions
     if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

```
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1 );

        return;



        }



 client.requestLocati onUpdates( request, callback, null );
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if GPS/Network has enabled. Then try to move to outdoor spaces.

Comment: I've already try but don't get result

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your code:

   LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
       ).setInterval( 0 ).setFastestInterval( 0 );
2. Please grant location permission to your application manually (since your code will ignore this)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get latitude and longitude:

```
    public static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private Location deviceLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getLocationPermission();

        if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){
           getDeviceLocation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
      permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

        switch(requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
                        if (grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                    //initialize
                    getDeviceLocation();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {FINE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CompassActivity.this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try{
            if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){

                final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();

                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                            deviceLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                            //Your code here

                        }
                    }

                });
            }else
                Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: Permission Failed");

        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
```